# Cual es la forma más sencilla de buscar un valor en un array?

Tags: array, excel, vba

Me surge la duda a la hora de localizar un determinado valor o string dentro de un array.

Existe algún método sencillo y rápido para hacerlo? 
Cómo solución se me ha ocurrido montar un diccionario con todos los elementos de un rango. Luego, en ese mismo diccionario coger los valores que voy a buscar y comprobar si existen en el diccionario.

¿Ideas?

Gracias.

Edito:

El tema de almacenar los valores en un diccionario lo tengo:

```
For i = 2 To UBound(arrJaula)

    If Not diccJaula.Exists(arrJaula(i, 1)) Then diccJaula.Add arrJaula(i, 1), 1

Next i
```

A partir de ahí recorreré los datos y si existe en el diccionario ya lo proceso a mi gusto.

La idea inicial era preguntar por búsquedas en arrays sin necesidad de montar un diccionario.

Tampoco entiendo que no se puedan pedir ideas en un mensaje. Hay veces que a la hora de plantear un problema lo primero es tener claras las ideas y no empezar a picar código para luego rehacerlo todo, pero bueno.

Comment: Hola. Edita la pregunta e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: Aunque para pedir opiniones por aquí no es para lo que está la web, si te puedo decir que es mejor colocar tus elementos en un diccionario y así puedes buscarlos (siempre y cuando sea un array 1D), luego puedes convertir ese diccionario en un array si es necesario `array = diccionario.keys`